# How to keep the div dimensions

Tags: html, css

Please consider the code below:

```html
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .section_divs {
      background-color: lightblue;
      float: left;
    }
    
    #section_empty {
      background-color: tomato;
      width: 10%;
    }
    
    #section_words {
      width: 80%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div class="section_divs" id="section_empty">a</div>
    <div class="section_divs" id="section_words">a</div>
    <div class="section_divs" id="section_empty">a</div>
  </section>
</body>
```

My problem is when I omit the letter a inside the div from:

```
<div class="section_divs" id="section_empty">a</div>
```

to

```
<div class="section_divs" id="section_empty"></div>
```

That div disappear, I want to know why this is happening? and is there any way that div can still have dimensions same as the other divs?

Comment: give it a min-height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with flexbox instead of floats. The parent element needs `display: flex` applied then give every child element a default `width: 10%` and add an additional class to the center `div` with `flex-grow: 1` for it to consume remaining space.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 10%; /* default size */
  background: tomato;
}

.item-center {
  flex-grow: 1; /* middle div will grow and stretch */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item item-center">a</div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">a</div>
  <div class="item item-center"></div>
  <div class="item">a</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's empty, the default height is 0.

If it has elements in it, height will fit content by default.

If you want to keep it at a specific height when it's empty, then give it `min-height`

```html
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      .section_divs {
        background-color: lightblue;
        float: left;
        min-height: 18px;
      }
      
      #section_empty {
        background-color: tomato;
        width: 10%;
      }
      
      #section_words {
        width: 80%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="section_divs" id="section_empty"></div>
      <div class="section_divs" id="section_words">b</div>
      <div class="section_divs" id="section_empty">c</div>
    </section>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mad7Dragon, your response also works, if only there is way to mark two responses.